# Override back button event of top menu issue in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, back-button

I want to back to previous activity from the current activity.

So I added this code to the current activity

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            //super.onBackPressed();
            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But it doesn't fires at all.

What do I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method in your `Activity` :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // the default resource ID of the actionBar's back button
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You get the clicked menu item `id` using `item.getItemId()`,
 then you check if it's equal to `android.R.id.home`, the default resource ID of the actionBar's back button.

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flag finishes all the old activities.

Comment: Yeah... It works fine for the bottom back button. But  I am asking for the TOP back arrow button that have created by default...

Comment: Well... I didn't created it. It  is created by Android Studio by default. So I Have no clue how to get reference to this button.